# Rcmd Check: Unexported objects imported by ':::' calls I have never used

Tags: r, package, knitr

I am trying to write my first R package. But with `Rcmd check` I always get the following message:

```
❯ checking dependencies in R code ... NOTE
Unexported object imported by a ':::' call: ‘knitr:::is_blank’
See the note in ?`:::` about the use of this operator.

0 errors ✔ | 0 warnings ✔ | 1 note ✖

R CMD check succeeded
```

But I have `is_blank()` never used in my R scripts!

I have used `knitr` (and `rmarkdown`) for the Vignettes:

```
%\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
```

And I have `knitr` (and `rmarkdown`) included in the Suggests and VignetteBuilder:

```
Suggests:
    knitr,
    rmarkdown
VignetteBuilder: 
    knitr,
    rmarkdown
```

I hope this information is enough to understand my difficulty. What is the problem respectively what did I wrong?

My package is at https://github.com/petzi53/coinsR and I am using R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26) on a Mac.

Answer (score 2):

Does the error still show when you remove/comment out the other lines with `:::` i.e.

```
fetch_yaml = bookdown:::fetch_yaml
load_config = blogdown:::load_config
split_yaml_body = blogdown:::split_yaml_body
```

in utils.R

Comment: This is the issue:  those assignments should have been flagged, but aren't because of deficiencies in the check code.  `blogdown:::split_yaml_body` makes the call to `knitr:::is_blank`, and that's where the message is coming from.

Comment: @BigBowlOfXoop: You are right, but the error changes to "no visible global function definition for ‘load_config’. Undefined global functions or variables: load_config". The same with the other lines, fetch_yaml, and split_yaml_body.

Comment: @user2554330 Yep! I pasted the functions `is_blank` and `split_yaml_body` into my scripts and removed the reference to `knitr:::` from `split_yaml_body`. Would you mind to provide your comment as an answer, so that I can accept it and vote it up?